# how to keep last time selected value in dropdownlist even after re-open app

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory

```
dropdown = '';
dropdown += '<option value="' + CONFIGURATOR.ChineseLanguage + '">Series 1520</option>\n';
dropdown += '<option value="' + CONFIGURATOR.EnglishLanguage + '">Series 1580</option>\n';
$('.tab-setup select[name=languageSelect]').html(dropdown);
```

html

```
<select class="dropdown" name="languageSelect" id="selectlanguage"></select>
```

datavariable.js

```
var CONFIGURATOR = {
    'ChineseLanguage': 'zh',
    'EnglishLanguage': 'en'
};
```

how to keep last time selected option in dropdownlist still appear even after re-open app

Comment: This would be one way: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: cool, even i use set local storage. it could keep the selection... but how do i show it  in dropdown list???????

Comment: Just follow the example in the link I assume: `$('.tab-setup select[name=languageSelect]').value(localStorage.getItem('myValue'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **localStorage** api to store the value, and it will be persisted even when the application is closed.

```
var dropdown = '',
    $select = $('.tab-setup select[name=languageSelect]'),
    storedValue = localStorage.getItem('languageSelectValue');

dropdown += '<option value="' + CONFIGURATOR.ChineseLanguage + '">Series 1520</option>\n';
dropdown += '<option value="' + CONFIGURATOR.EnglishLanguage + '">Series 1580</option>\n';

$select.html(dropdown);

//Set the initial value if any
if (storedValue) {
    $select.val(storedValue);
}

//Bind a listener to store the selected value in localStorage
$select.on('change', function () {
    localStorage.setItem('languageSelectValue', $(this).val());
});
```